# Golang web spider with pagination processing

Tags: go, concurrency, pagination, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm working on a golang web crawler that should parse the search results on some specific search engine. The main difficulty - parsing with concurrency, or rather, in processing pagination such as 
`← Previous 1 2 3 4 5 ... 34 Next →`.  All things work fine except recursive crawling of paginated results. Look at my code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"

    "github.com/antchfx/htmlquery"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

type Spider struct {
    HandledUrls []string
}

func NewSpider(url string) *Spider {
    // ...
}

func requestProvider(request string) string {
    // Everything is good here
}

func connectProvider(url string) net.Conn {
    // Also works
}

// getContents makes request to search engine and gets response body
func getContents(request string) *html.Node {
    // ...
}

// CheckResult controls empty search results
func checkResult(node *html.Node) bool {
    // ...
}

func (s *Spider) checkVisited(url string) bool {
    // ...
}

// Here is the problems
func (s *Spider) Crawl(url string, channelDone chan bool, channelBody chan *html.Node) {
    body := getContents(url)

    defer func() {
        channelDone <- true
    }()

    if checkResult(body) == false {
        err := errors.New("Nothing found there")
        ErrFatal(err)
    }

    channelBody <- body
    s.HandledUrls = append(s.HandledUrls, url)
    fmt.Println("Handled ", url)

    newUrls := s.getPagination(body)

    for _, u := range newUrls {
        fmt.Println(u)
    }

    for i, newurl := range newUrls {
        if s.checkVisited(newurl) == false {
            fmt.Println(i)
            go s.Crawl(newurl, channelDone, channelBody)
        }
    }
}

func (s *Spider) getPagination(node *html.Node) []string {
    // ...
}

func main() {
    request := requestProvider(*requestFlag)
    channelBody := make(chan *html.Node, 120)
    channelDone := make(chan bool)

    var parsedHosts []*Host

    s := NewSpider(request)

    go s.Crawl(request, channelDone, channelBody)

    for {
        select {
        case recievedNode := <-channelBody:
             // ...

            for _, h := range newHosts {
                 parsedHosts = append(parsedHosts, h)
                 fmt.Println("added", h.HostUrl)
            }

        case <-channelDone:
            fmt.Println("Jobs finished")
        }

        break
   }
}
```

It always returns the **first page only**, no pagination. Same GetPagination(...) works good. Please tell me, where is my error(s).
Hope Google Translate was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that `main` exits before all goroutine finished.

First, there is a `break` after the `select` statement and it runs uncodintionally after first time a channel is read. That ensures the `main` func returns after the first time you send something over `channelBody`.

Secondly, using `channelDone` is not the right way here. The most idomatic approach would be using a `sync.WaitGroup`. Before starting each goroutine, use `WG.Add(1)` and replace the `defer` with `defer WG.Done()`; In `main`, use `WG.Wait()`. Please be aware that you should use a pointer to refer to the `WaitGroup`. You can read more [here](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).